# Upload files - Cant find BROWSE button control windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I want to upload my files from windows phone 7 to my server using web service via HTTPRequest or WebClient.

But i could not find the "Browse" button from where user can select the file to upload.

Can anyone point me they ways from which user can select the file to upload?

Answer (score 3):

There is no browse functionality in Windows Phone 7. Windows Phone does not have the concept of a 'hard drive' containing user documents like a Windows PC does.

There are various ways to get at specific types of files, such as Pictures via the various "Choosers" that Microsoft provides. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543(v=vs.92).aspx

If the documents are documents you have created then you will likely have stored them in Isolated Storage (the only disk space your app has access to) so you will have to provide the browser functionality yourself as only you will know what files are there and which the user should be able to upload.

Comment: Thank you. I want user to upload and share the file with others. So every file in his phone will be in isolated storage? Can i move file into isolated storage? Sorry, but this is my first app so fairly new here.

Comment: What file? There are no files on a phone.

Comment: Take this scenario. User has the abc.doc file on his phone received via bluetooth. Now he want to upload this file using the app. How can select this file? Is this file will be stored in isolated storage only so from where i can access it with app?

Comment: The user can't receive a file 'via bluetooth' in Windows Phone.